# Changing columns in array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, permutation, swap

I have trouble with swapping columns.I have int[n][n] matrix.Next I have list(with size n!) with arrays(with length n) and it include all permutations of numbers 1,2,...,N([2,1,3,4,..,n][1,4,3,2,..,n]....etc)). And for each permutation in this list i want to make specific matrices with different order of columns. Here is my code which does not work:

```
int[][] matrix={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
Arraylist<int[][]> matrices=new Arraylist<>();
for (int[] permute : permutations)
{
     int[][] newMatrix=matrix;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
         {
         if (permute[i] == i + 1)
             continue;
         }
       newMatrix=swapColumn(newMatrix, i, permute[i] - 1);
}
matrices.add(newMatrix.clone());    
}
```

method swapColumn works correctly.Condition is there due to swapping the same column. When i print the matrices it print  n!* original matrix
Could anyone help me?

Comment: permutations is of what data type ? posting an example input and output would help.

Comment: I don't see any array named temp in the code. did you mean matrix?

Comment: yes. i edit this, sorry @ForeverStudent

Comment: @shreshtabm i add info about in,out

Comment: The i in newMatrix=swapColumn(newMatrix, i, permute[i] - 1); is out of scope because i is declared in the for loop

Comment: Yes, but it change column i for column permute[i]-1 ( for example  second column for third column)

Comment: How can it happen? i is a local variable and you cannot use it after the scope of your for loop.

Comment: Did you create a copy of `newMatrix` in `swapColumn` method because in line `int[][] newMatrix = matrix;` you are not making a copy, you are only referencing the original `matrix`? Can you show your `swapColumn` method and the code where you print your matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **First thing**

this can not even compile since you are using      `newMatrix=swapColumn(newMatrix, i, permute[i] - 1);` out of the loop scope and the i is not declared out of the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
         {
         if (permute[i] == i + 1)
             continue;
         }`
```

- **second thing** :

  the function `swapColumn` what it does is copy the column source to column destination so the original value of column destination is lost so the moment when you need it to put it in an other column you won't have it all what you would have is the new affected value
- **Third Thing**

the  `matrices.add(newMatrix.clone())`;  is out of the scope of the permutation loop so it will raise a compilation error since newMatix is declared inside the loop scope